# Partial derivatives and chain rule exercise

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ be a function of class $C^2$ and $g:\mathbb R^2->\mathbb R$ the function given by $g(r,θ):f(r\cos(θ),r\sin(θ))$. If $f_x(1,1)=f_{yy}(1,1)=1$ and $f_{xx}(1,1)=f_y(1,1)=0$, what is the value of $\dfrac{∂^2g}{∂r\,∂θ}(\sqrt{2},\pi/4)$?

It's an exercise I was given in my Calculus II course. I spent a lot of time thinking about it and I don't even know how to start it, I feel stupid. Could someone explain to me how to solve it step by step? I have an exam soon and I need to know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain rule for partial derivatives is
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \lambda} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \lambda}$$ So when you take partial derivatives of $f$ w.r.t. $r$ and $\theta$ you can express this as derivatives w.r.t. $x$ and $y$, which you know the values of. To start you off:
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$$ and since $x = r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$,
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cos\theta + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\sin\theta$$ Once you get an expression for $g_{r\theta}$ you'll find everything works out nicely when putting in the values you are given, as $r=\sqrt{2}$, $\theta=\pi /4$ give nice values for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: How do you find an expression for grθ?

Comment: So $g_{r\theta}$ is shorthand for $\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial r \partial \theta}$. Given we have $\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}$ we just need to differentiate w.r.t. $\theta$ to get the final expression into which the values can be plugged.

Comment: Can I see everything as a constant except for cosθ and sinθ? I know I'm asking stupid questions, sorry.

Comment: It's ok. You are right that, because obviously $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ depend on $\theta$ you have to differentiate them as you normally would, but both $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ indirectly depend on $\theta$ too, through their arguments $x$ and $y$. So when it comes to handling them, you use the chain rule, to get $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta \partial x} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}$ and likewise for the other one